# Why can't we feed datetime to Linear Regression and how does toordinal() different from any other integer datatype?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm working with dates for the first time. First I knew I had to convert it to timestamps which gave me the values in "datetime64" values. But then I came to know that Linear Regression from sklearn does not accept datetime as dtype for regression. Why is that? Also, after executing `df.date = df.date.map(datetime.toordinal)` I saw that the datatype for the column is "int64". How does the sklearn LinearRegression know it is not any random int64 dataand a datetime data (considering the fact that I got the needed model after plotting)?

Comment: it doesnt know it isnt any random int64 ... it just views them as x values to an axis basically (over simplified)

Comment: The regression function needs a float type variable, and toordinal will provide this by calculating the number of days (with decimals) since  January 1st, year 1

Comment: So how does it work so well considering its just a range of values (like index) and give the required prediction. Because then there is absolute zero correlation between the date and the target variable?

Comment: I don't understand your concern. The date Oct. 9 2020 can be expressed in various formats, for example a number of days since a given date. This is similar to expressing the time of day as number of seconds since midnight, or temperature as degrees above water's freezing point

Comment: cross-posted at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/82781/55122